# (Python 3) How do I combine products of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

input:

```
Choc 5
Vani 10
Stra 7
Choc 3
Stra 4
END

def process_input(lst):
    result = []
    for string in lines:
        A=string.split()
        result.append([A[0],int(A[1])])  
    return result

def merge_products(invent):
    # your code here


# DON’T modify the code below
str = input()
lines = []
while str != 'END':
    lines.append(str)
    str = input()
inventory1 = process_input(lines)
merge_products(inventory1)
print(inventory1)
```

---

from this output

```
[['Choc', 5], ['Vani', 10], ['Stra', 7], ['Choc', 3], ['Stra', 4]]
```

I need to get this output

```
[['Choc', 8], ['Vani', 10], ['Stra', 11]]
```

How do I combine the integers under same string?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Kaushik NP's answer, but implemented using `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
def merge_products(inventory):
    groceries = Counter()
    for item, count in inventory:
        groceries[item] +=count

    return [[item, count] for item, count in groceries.items()]
```

This is functionally equivalent, but `Counter` takes care of the default value for you.  It is also probably more performant for large lists of items, but at the scale you are operating it is probably not a big deal.

Comment: Have you tested your solution? I think what you want is this `groceries.update({item:count})`.

Comment: @atru: Both should work (`update` takes both an input dict and `**kwargs` on normal `dict`s, and while the documentation doesn't mention it for `Counter`, it works for `Counter` too). That said, both of those effectively make unnecessary temporary `dict`s one way or the other; `groceries[item] += count` would make more sense when it's just updating the count for one item (`Counter` implements `__missing__`, so when the key doesn't exist, it still returns `0` without raising `KeyError`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for the explanation, but then when I use the original code and the list in the OP all I get is `['item':29]`. How come? I tested it with my own Python 2.7 and an online Python 3.X.

Comment: @atru I changed it to groceries[item] += count, this will solve the issue.

Comment: @atru: Don't know what to tell you. On a local test on Python 3.6, `c = Counter()`, `c.update(item=1)`, `print(c)` produced `Counter({'item': 1})`. Might differ by version? As I noted, the documentation doesn't mention `kwargs` support, so it might be broken in some versions.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's all expected, what this was producing for some reason was a Counter object of a single entry called item with a count that logically corresponded to the sum of all values. As if the call to counter did not interpret the actual value of item at a given iteration. Current solution works - and definitely a good point on the extra dictionary creation.

Comment: @BrandonDube just for future reference, did your original solution produced the expected result?

Comment: @BrandonDube According to the requirements in the question, you have to modify the list passed and return nothing.

Comment: @balki I would rather show how to solve the problem than get full marks on the homework.

Comment: @atru It actually did not -- I wrote it without testing it and assumed the kwargs form of Counter.update would carry the key through, but it doesn't.

Comment: @BrandonDube Good to know altogether. If you want I can delete all these extra comments including this one, so they don't go in the way of a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultdict` to store the values and add to them.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_products(invent):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for x,y in invent:
            d[x]+=y
    return [[k,v] for k,v in d.items()]
```

#driver values :

```
>>> merge_products([['Choc', 5], ['Vani', 10], ['Stra', 7], ['Choc', 3], ['Stra', 4]])
=> [['Choc', 8], ['Vani', 10], ['Stra', 11]]
```

---

And incase you want to *preserve the order* in which you find them too, use an `OrderedDict` instead.

```
def merge_products(invent):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for x,y in invent:
        if d.get(x,None)==None :
            d[x]=y
        else :
            d[x]+=y

    return [[k,v] for k,v in d.items()]
```

Comment: `collections.Counter` might be a bit nicer than a defaultdict for this.

Comment: @BrandonDube : how would `Counter` be useful here? I am not extremely proficient in its usage, but I don't think it would work out here. If it can be, could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, I posted an example as an answer.  It is nearly identical to your defaultdict implementation, but the name "Counter" is more clear about what is happening vs the mysterious name "defaultdict."

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary:

```
def merge_products(invent):
    # your code here
    result = {}
    for item in invent:
        if item[0] not in result:
            result[item[0]] = item[1]
        else:
            result[item[0]] += item[1]

    return result
```

note that you will use the returned value, not the one passed as parameter:

```
print(merge_products(inventory1))
```